# How do I write a TFS 2010 Work Item query clause whos value is a field value?

Tags: wiql

*I think this question may be spawned from lack of knowledge, but here we go...*

I am trying to write a *new team query* (using the new query option of team explorer, *in VS 2010*) what I want is fairly simple; essentially a list of work items whos [Completed Work] value exceeds the [Original Estimate] field value.  In other words WIs that have exceeded their original estimates.

The VS 2010 view does not seem to have an option to show the WIQL being generated under the hood, so I'll have to describe what I have done/am trying to do via the VS 2010 UI.

Clauses are fairly standard to start;
    *Team Project = @Project*
    *And Work Item type = Task*
    *And State = [Any]*

I have added a caluse (to remove any work items without an estimate)
    *And Orignial Estimate <> ''*

I thought the next step would be simplicity itself; adding a clause along the lines of
    *And Completed Work > Original Estimate*

But no matter how I try to write "Original Estimate" in the value filed of the UI (as **Original Estimate**, **[Original Estimate]** and many other variations) to date all I get is a line indicating a that **Input string was not in a correct format**.

Is this possible? I would have thought simple comparisons to the value of another WI field would be supported, are they?  If it is possible what the he** is the syntax?

Thanks.

## Update

I had a look at the Task template and confirmed that both **Original Estimate** and **Remaining Work** are doubles and have the following full names (should that be relivant)

```
     Friendly Name       Type      Ref Name     
     Original Estimate   Double    Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.OriginalEstimate
     Remaining Work      Double    Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.RemainingWork
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need the >= [Field] operator instead of the >= operator:

> Original Estimate >= [Field]  Completed
>   Work

Comment: Well thanks for that :-) +1 for the answer and -1 to me for being so blind to the options in the UI drop down!