# In a TFS 2010 Work Item Query can I add two field values as the "Value"?

Tags: wiql

**I would like to create a team query for our TFS users that shows all task items where the sum of the [hours remaining] and [hours completed] fields exceed the [original estimate] value.**

Now Whilst I can add a clause to the WIQL that compares one field to the value of **ONE** other field (Which I had to ask you kind folks in stack exchange how to do in [How do I write a TFS 2010 Work Item query clause whose value is a field value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5870559/how-do-i-write-a-tfs-2010-work-item-query-clause-whos-value-is-a-field-value) which was answered by [PVitt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/128886/pvitt) with  admirable politeness - Since I had simply failed to read the "operator" drop down properly!)

I am struggling to find a way of querying the sum of two fields.

For example:

This query clause works;

```
And Completed Work > [Field] Remaining Work
```

What I really want is something along the lines of;

```
And Completed Work > [Field] Remaining Work+Original Estimate
```

The problem is either this cannot be done, or my *wild guesses* as to the correct syntax for summing two field values have all been wrong.

Specifying two filenames separated with a **+** just yields a **TF51005 error** [image: TF51005 dialog]

Similarly guessing at a "macro" like Sum(Remaining Work+Original Estimate) or Sum(Remaining Work,Original Estimate) results in the same.

**So is this even possible?
if it is how would I go about this?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is not possible. Your options are to use:
1) the object model to write C# code that iterates over the work items from a query and do the math yourself
2) run the query in excel and do the calculations and filter in excel
3) use ssrs to create a report that does the math for you

If you think this is important, you can always post your suggestion on user voice: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com

Answer (score 3):

Add a new hidden field to store the sum, install [TFS Aggregator](http://tfsaggregator.codeplex.com/) and set it up to update the hidden field when the workitem is updated.

Then perform your queries off the new field.

There may be a couple of minutes delay between updating the sum having the new value.

```
<AggregatorItem operationType="Numeric" operation="Sum" linkType="Self" workItemType="Task">
<TargetItem name="Total Work"/>
<SourceItem name="Remaining Work"/>
<SourceItem name="Original Estimate"/>
</AggregatorItem>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're soley focused on the results/don't mind a (short) trip outside TFS, what I do is run the TFS query that produces the individual results I need, then just select all/copy/paste the results grid into Excel.  There you'll have access to all Excel's suming and auto (col headers)/[advanced filtering](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/filter-by-using-advanced-criteria-HP005200178.aspx) capabilities.  You can define criteria that reference other cells using this method as well.  Can also use the "If()" fcn to (in/ex)clude cell values in straight formulas.  W/ some Excel fancy footwork, should even be able to preserve the summing fcns btw runs/pastes.